# Optimize likelihood function to get lambda for Box-Cox transform of two variables

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, data-transformation

I'm trying to implement the Transformed Normal method (TN) that was described in Faraggi, D., & Reiser, B. (2002). Estimation of the area under the ROC curve. Statistics in medicine, 21(20), 3093–3106.

The authors transform the measurements of a diseased and a non-diseased sample to normality using a common $\hat{\lambda}$ in the Box-Cox-transformation and then proceed to calculate a cutpoint using normal theory.

The $\hat{\lambda}$ is obtained according to Zou, K. H., Tempany, C. M., Fielding, J. R., & Silverman, S. G. (1998). Original smooth receiver operating characteristic curve estimation from continuous data: Statistical methods for analyzing the predictive value of spiral CT of ureteral stones. Academic Radiology, 5(10), 680–687. https://doi.org/10.1016/S1076-6332(98)80562-X

Here's the relevant part of the latter paper:

[image: parametric_transformation]

So a profile log likelihood function is constructed and optimized to find $\hat{\lambda}$. $x_{0,i}$ and $y_{0,j}$ are the original, unaltered measurements and $x'$ and $y'$ are the Box-Cox-transformed ones, if I understand the paper correctly.

I am now trying to implement this likelihood function in R. Apparently, the Box-Cox-transformed variables are inserted into the likelihood function, so my attempt looks like this:

```
boxcox <- function(x, lambda) {
    if (lambda == 0) {
        return(log(x))
    } else {
        ((x**lambda) - 1) / lambda
    }
}

profile_loglik <- function(lambda, x, y) {
    m <- length(x)
    n <- length(y)
    x_t <- boxcox(x, lambda)
    y_t <- boxcox(y, lambda)
    return(-m * log(sd(x_t)) - n * log(sd(y_t)) + (lambda - 1) * (sum(log(x_t)) + sum(log(y_t))))
}

calc_lambda_hat <- function(x, y) {
    optim_func <- function(lambda) -(profile_loglik(lambda = lambda, x = x, y = y))
    optim(0.5, optim_func, method = "Brent", lower = 0, upper = 100)
}

# Example data
x <- rlnorm(200)
y <- rlnorm(100, 0.4, 0.4)
calc_lambda_hat(x, y)

# Result:
$par
[1] 100

$value
[1] NaN

$counts
function gradient 
      NA       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

# Plus lots of warnings...
```

The data of Zou et al. seem to be roughly lognormally distributed and so is the data I have in mind, so the method should be applicable. However, since some of the $x'$ and $y'$ will become negative after the Box-Cox transformation, terms like $log(x')$ in the likelihood function become `NaN`. If I insert $x_0$ and $y_0$ instead of $x'$ and $y'$ into the likelihood function, it is a monotonically increasing function.

Thus, my question is: What are the mistakes in my implementation? Thank you.

Comment: The log being taken in the likelihood there would be for the variable before transformation, would it not? If you say it's lognormal, then the values will all be positive

Comment: Thank you for responding. Yes, if I use the original measurements x_0 and y_0 all values will be positive but then the likelihood function is a linear, monotonically increasing function. I tried that in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bantis, L. E., Nakas, C. T. and Reiser, B. (2014), Construction of confidence regions in the ROC space after the estimation of the optimal Youden index‐based cut‐off point. Biom, 70: 212-223. doi:10.1111/biom.12107 implements the method and gives the following formula:

[image]

We see that they use the transformed values when calculating the standard deviations (in the square brackets) but the untransformed values in the third row of the formula.

Again, I implemented this in R and this time my only quibble is that $-\frac{n_X}{2}$ and $-\frac{n_Y}{2}$ apparently should be replaced by just $-n_X$ and $-n_Y$, which are in my understanding the numbers of observations in both groups, otherwise the results are way off. The R code thus is:

```
profile_loglik <- function(lambda, x, y) {
    m <- length(x)
    n <- length(y)
    x_t <- boxcox(x, lambda)
    y_t <- boxcox(y, lambda)
    -m * log(sd(x_t)) - n * log(sd(y_t)) + (lambda - 1) * (sum(log(x)) + sum(log(y)))
}

calc_lambda_hat <- function(x, y) {
    optim_func <- function(lambda) -(profile_loglik(lambda = lambda, x = x, y = y))
    optim(0.5, optim_func, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = -4, upper = 10)
}
```

I tested `calc_lambda_hat` against concatenating both groups and then using `forecast::BoxCox.lambda(c(x, y), "loglik")`. The correlation of the returned values for $\lambda$ after 1000 repetitions in various scenarios with lognormal distributions is about 85%, so this way the implementation seems to be OK.